# How to do data binding onclick button using Angular 6

Tags: angular

Is there any way to retrieve data from a json file and bind it to two or more forms by clicking a button?
->There are 2 buttons.
One to post data to json file(done) and other to replicate the data that is entered in the form to two other forms.

Comment: You can make a copy of the object and assign it to `ngModel`. Please provide your code for us to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

you can use load-json-file npm package for read your json file and then binding data  to your model :

```
loadJsonFile('foo.json').then(json => {
console.log(json);

//sample:   
 const data = json; 
 this.property = json.foo;
//end sample
```

});

sample code for click event:

html:

```
//<button (click)="onClickMe()">Click me!</button>
//<p>{{property}}</p>
```

comonentfile.ts:
    function onClickMe(){

```
loadJsonFile('foo.json').then(json => {
console.log(json);

//sample:   
 const data = json; 
 this.property = json.foo;
//end sample

});

}
```

Comment: This entire thing will come in a function that will be triggered onclick right?

Comment: @kedked yes , i edit my answer and write sample code

Comment: Do we need to import that package?

Comment: @kedked yes install this package with this command: npm install load-json-file

Answer (score 0):

We can make an HTTP request to load JSON files.

```
    import { Http } from '@angular/http';

    myData = new MyData();
    constructor(public http: Http ) { }

        getData() {
          this.http.get("FILE-URL/TO/JSON/FILE") // URL to your file like -> "assets/data.json"
          .map(res => return res.json())
          .subscribe(data => {
             //here data is JSON object
             this.myData = data;
          })
      }

class MyData {
  public prop1: string,
  public prop2: string
}
```

You can bind the **myData** class properties to your form fields.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myData.prop1">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myData.prop2">
</form>
```